# Is there a way to make custom coffee foam?

Tags: modeling, texturing

I want to make a cup of coffee with the nice swirl of white and brown foam, but I want to be able to influence it using an object (similar to how they make hearts in cappuccino).  In this case it's an .svg logo I would import.  I've seen lots of examples where image textures were used for foam, but I'm wondering if there's a way to actually influence the foam in Blender itself.  Is this possible?

Here's an example of the type of foam I am going for:

[image]

And here is an example of a logo I would want to use as the design in the foam:

[image]

EDIT:

Here are the changes I made based on responses provided.  I modified the node setup slightly in that I did not use the coffee nodes as I decided to just use an image texture for that.  Unfortunately, it made the logo part heavily distorted and I'm not sure why.

Here's the node setup:

[image]

Here's the result:

[image]

I've attached the .blend:

**NEW EDIT:**

Based on the follow up answers provided, here is the finished render (including blur techniques used in GIMP):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use the image as a mask to separate two shaders and as a bump map.

Comment: Convert the svg to a bitmap image. Use the image to mix two textures.

Comment: This may be of some help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rNrL7a12xg&t=2694s

Comment: @Timaroberts do you mean using a mix shader with both images?

Comment: @cegaton same question I asked Tim

Comment: @icYou520 thanks!  I checked it out before asking this question, but it didn't have the effect I was looking for.

Comment: Using the image as a factor to mix different shaders.

Comment: @lakerice it is easier to help you if you post images and information on your  current project.

Comment: @cegaton I've posted my images and .blend

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not extremely good, but this should give you a good place to start:
[image: Render 1]
[image: Render 2]

The image you want to appear on the foam is very detailed and hard to reproduce on real coffee. This is why I thought it should be pre-processed in some image editing software to make it more realistic and doable. I used Photoshop to smudge out the image a bit, and I got this:
[image: Texture]

The coffee itself that I made in Blender was a simple squeezed sphere. I then used the image above as a texture to determine the color of the foam. Here is my node setup for the foam:
[image: Setup]
I'll go into the details now.

## Distorting the image

I used a `Wave` texture to distort the image in rings. You can adjust the frequency and amplitude of the distortions.
[image: Distortion]

## Some noise texture on top of that

I added some noise to the image, because *nocoffee is perfect*.
[image: Noise]

## Bump map

I didn't have any actual coffee to look at, but I'm assuming that the image should have some effect on the bumps in the foam, due to stirring. So I created some "ripple" bumps around the borders of the texture (kinda):
[image: Bump map]

## The coffee shader

Now, we have calculated both the texture we want on the coffee and the bump map. I used a gradient to get the right coffee colors. The actual shader was a simple mix of a diffuse shader and a glossy shader:
[image: Shader]

Here is my resulting `.blend` file you can play with:

[image]

Here are some possible improvements you could consider:
- It is very easy to adjust how much you want the image to be distorted in rings. In the "Distort Image" frame, just change the second value of the `Divide` math node.
- Consider introducing a subsurface scattering component, because coffee is transparent. Or, even better, use a volume shader. Coffee is a little bit transparent.
- You could change the colors to make them a little warmer, because my coffee looks like mud. Yuck. :)
- You could further tweak the original image: smudge it, adjust contrast, add noise, etc.

Comment: thanks for this incredibly detailed answer and effort!  Unfortunately I was not able to reproduce the result (I tried to create the nodes from scratch so I could better understand).  I've posted the .blend and my setup in my revised question.  Let me know what you think...

Comment: @lakerice I think you're on the right track! I looked at your node setup, and noticed two mistakes: you used a `color mix` node instead of the `mix shader`, and the `math` node where you need a `vector math` node. [Here is a .blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4433/) where I fixed these mistakes, so the texture works now. But you still need to work with the colors. Good luck! :)

Comment: Oh that makes sense!  It's easy to mix up (no pun intended) those nodes.  One more question: is it possible to make the logo bubbly like the coffee texture?  Or make it take on the bump of the coffee texture?

Comment: @lakerice, I'm not sure what you mean by a "bubbly" logo, but you can definitely add a bump map with bubbles. I would try to use the `Voronoi texture` with a scale of ~150, and plug that into the `Bump` node (you can input a `normal` in the `bump` node to combine two bump textures). Then send the output to the material's `normal`. (You could also mask it so that it only affects the logo, but that's too long to explain in a comment.)

Comment: sorry for the late response.  I tried using the voronoi but I wasn't able to achieve a realistic result (at least the way I tried) but I ended up using the bump for the coffee image for the logo as well so they basically followed the same texture.  Also, I used blur techniques in GIMP to get a more blended result (I'm sure there's a way in Blender but for convenience sake I just manipulated the logo .png itself).  You can see my finished result in my question if you like :)  Thanks again for your help!