# Realistic coffe foam

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing

Good day!
Сan anyone help me please?
How can i create realistic coffee foam? [image]

I am new to blender and don’t know much. 
Here is my nodes. 
[image]
I took a 2D cooffee foam texture from google and created a normal map at https://cpetry.github.io/NormalMap-Online/.

But i'm sure that there is an option to create more realistic foam.

Comment: Do you mean the crema of an espresso?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72495/create-a-gradient-effect-like-for-coffee https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98861/is-there-a-way-to-make-custom-coffee-foam